# constant zoom in the Photos app on Mac when switching between photos

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app

I am playing with Photos app on my Mac and I would like to have fixed zoom while switching between photos. This is the option in Photos app:

[image]

Right now, it jumps to 0% every time I switch to another photo. I would like to have it fixed all the time. Any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there is no option to lock the zoom in the Photo app. You will need another app to achieve that effect.