# How to maintain the zoom level while going back and forth between photos in MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, photos, zoom

I would like to inspect photos pixel-wise, and I want the zoom level to stay at the exact same level&location when I skip to the next photo. What is the most plausible way to do this on a MacBook, an app or another fix? Thanks!

P.S.: I am aware of [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/249068/constant-zoom-in-the-photos-app-on-mac-when-switching-between-photos) post, but I cannot comment there due to my reputation here.